# Missing folder in iCloud drive!

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, folders, markdown

Installed [MWeb](http://www.mweb.im/) for iOS and it created a folder, its available in my phone's iCloud drive but not in Web or Mac iCloud drive! Created a test folder and made sure no sync issues. Any help is appreciated